# Why doesn't the transition work?

Tags: css, transactions, css-transitions

So, I'm trying to make a dropdown menu with a nice transition but can't get it to work as it should. I'm sure theres a simple error somewhere or I ommited something important, but it's my first website and I can't find it...

```
nav ul li:hover>ul li {
display: inline-block;
visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: visibility 1s ease;
  -o-transition: visibility 1s ease;
  transition: visibility 1s ease;
}
ul li ul li{
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

I suppose that's all the important code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate "display" property. It must be always set to a different value than "none".

Check this demo :

http://shailan.com/demos/css3-transitions-dropdown.html

Comment: Damn :( I tried setting it to display: inline-block already, but then the menu becomes visible when I hover over the place where it should appear, and I want it to appear when hovering on it's parent li element. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Links can decay and may become invalid in future, it would greatly improve your answer if you edited a summary of the linked page into it.